# Implementation of One-to-Many Relationships with Document References using mongodb and spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data, one-to-many

I want to use spring data with mongodb and want to implement a one to many relationship using document reference.
db should look like this:

```
 {
    _id = 123451232
    "countryName":"India",
    "status":"true",
    "meetings":[123451233, 123451234]
 }

{
  _id = 123451233
   "countryName":"china",
   "status":"true"
}

{
  _id = 123451234
   "countryName":"china",
   "status":"true"
}
```

TO achieve this i used dbRef

### country model

```
@Document(collection = "country")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Field("country_id")
    private String countryId;

    @Field("country_name")
    @Indexed
    private String countryName;

    @Field("status")
    private boolean status = true;

    @DBRef
    private List<Country> meetings= new ArrayList<Country>();

    // getters and setters
```

i got an error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id.
```

Comment: I think you first need to do is to save the `Country` data (if they're present). After this, get the saved countries back (normally if you save an object you get the persisted entity back). Fill your country object with the saved entities and save the object.

Comment: I had the same problem, but then I changed my implementation from adding list of `Items` in a `Blog` entity (i.e. `OneToMany`) to adding the Reference of the `Blog` in the `Item` entity. I didn't get any issues with this approach (so far xD). Here the Two entities: [Blog](https://github.com/RawSanj/blogAggr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rawsanj/blogaggr/domain/Blog.java) and [Item](https://github.com/RawSanj/blogAggr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rawsanj/blogaggr/domain/Item.java) . Although it will be great to know the solution for your question.

Comment: Create a meetings  object with these format and try it   List<Long> meetings =new ArrayList<Long>() or else use string ,double data type

Comment: Countries in the meeting collection must be saved at first. it's why you got the error.